# Creating and reading from appconfig.json

Tags: c#, webapi, appsettings

I am trying to create config that will contains a list of servers, with extra values, something like

```
"Servers": [
{
  "Name": ".",
  "Type": "A"
},
{
  "Name": "Fred",
  "Type":  "B"
}
]
```

Is that the correct way to structure the config file?

I then haven't been able to find a way to read from the config based on the above set up.

```
var test = Configuration.GetSection("Servers").GetChildren();

        //List<Server> Servers = new List<Server>();
        foreach (var testItem in test)
        {
            Server server = new Server()
            {
                //Name = testItem.GetValue(,"Name"),
                //Type = testItem.GetValue("Type")
            };
            Servers.Add(server);
        }
```

I'd appreciate some guidance on how to set up the config, and then how to read those values.

Thanks for reading

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71974647/analog-of-configurationmanager-in-dotnet-6-and-netstandard-2-0-and-protected-se

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653752/1704458

Comment: They do not seem relevant to my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
List<Server> servers = configuration.GetSection("Servers").Get<List<Server>>();
 
public class Server
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
}
```